# Does not play mp3

Tags: java, jmf

I use Java Media Framework.

I did whatever was played mp3, but many of them do not want to play.

Why?

this file not play http://depositfiles.com/files/7py43atpw

Comment: Need more info. What operating system? Which version of JMF did you install. Is the program throwing any kind of exceptions. Did you install the performance pack?

Comment: I use windows (XP) but need to work in win7. jmf2.1.1e. "performance pack" - I not understand. Exceptions - not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're use [JMF MP3 Plugin](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html) properly, all should be fine. Probably you should give us your code sample.

Update: 
Also, you could try [JavaLayer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javalayer/)

Comment: it's Good! My song is play! You do not know of examples from the visual interface?

Comment: Unfortunately, can't find any examples. But it isn't a complex thing, you just need to find simple example of [Swing app](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) (music player is just a several buttons, isn't it?:)). Also, I guess you will need to be familiar with [Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) in java. Good luck!

Comment: Look into `Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();` where mediaPlayer is your `Player` object

Answer (score 2):

This library is full of bugs. And even when you'll manage to play a mp3, try it on mac or unix and you will get a surprise.